# Automatically create folder in new users' home directory

Tags: users, home-directory, autostart, adduser, skel

I need to automatically assign every new user that gets created a certain folder `Sales` in their home directory. (e.g. when you add the user `tim`, `tim` automatically gets a folder named `Sales` in his home directory)

How can I do this?

Comment: Unsure if this is what you are looking for but the [`adduser`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser) command has hooks to customize e.g. the directory layout for newly created accounts.

Comment: Hi user_01 did you notice the answers? Could you let us know if it is helpful (or not), or if anything is clear?

Answer (score 6):

All new users' home directories are copies of `/etc/skel` when the user gets created through any method that automatically creates a home directory.

If you are sure that you need the `Sales` folder on every new user account's home directory, you can just create the folder in `/etc/skel`.

---

Make sure the owner and permission of everything you create or modify in there is correct.

Set the permissions you want, they will be copied to the new user's home directory as they are. Usually you take `644` (octal representation) or `rw-r--r--` (string representation). You can modify this with one the commands below. Make sure everything is owner-readable and all directories are owner-executable (otherwise the owner can't list or access their content).

- `sudo chmod 644 /etc/skel/FILE_OR_DIRECTORY` to set permissions for a single file or directory using the octal representation.
- `sudo chmod u=rw,g=r,o=r /etc/skel/FILE_OR_DIRECTORY` to set permissions for a single file or directory using a syntax similar to the string representation.
- `sudo chmod -R 644 /etc/skel` to recursively set permissions for all files and directories using the octal representation.
- `sudo chmod -R u=rw,g=r,o=r /etc/skel` to recursively set permissions for all files and directoriesusing a syntax similar to the string representation.

The owner should be `root`. You change this recursively on all files and folders in `/etc/skel` with the command below:

```
sudo chown -R root: /etc/skel
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple alternative would be to create a starter in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, that will create a folder in (any) user's home directory on log in, *only* if the folder does not exist yet.

- Create a file with the following lines:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Create Sales
  Exec=/bin/bash -c "mkdir ~/Sales"
  Type=Application
  ```
- Save it as `sales.desktop` (the extension is essential)
- Run the command:

  ```
  sudo cp /path/to/sales.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart
  ```

This will create a folder `~/Sales` in the home directory of *any* user once he or she logs in (only if it doesn't exist).

#### Explanation

To run a command on startup (log in actually) locally, f*or one user only*, we can put a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`

If we do the same, but store the `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, the command runs locally as well, but similarly *for any user* on log in.

If we make the `.desktop` file run the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "mkdir ~/Sales"
```

we make sure the folder is created, even re- created on the next log in if the user might remove it manually. At the same time, if the folder exists, the command will not be executed, so existing folders will not be overwritten.